# kivy GUI does not adapt to 'Customize display' on windows

Tags: windows, kivy, screen-resolution, screen-density

I just have a new laptop with 14" screen and resolution of 1920 x 1080 running windows 10. As everything on the screen becomes very small I have set the "Change the size of text, apps and other items" option to 125%.
Applications like Office and PyCharm enlarge and look crispy and clear. Unfortunately, my kivy app becomes blurry and vague.

What do I need to do to get this crispy and clear as well?

Comment: This suggests that the kivy app is being scaled badly by the system rather than aware of the true resolution. I thought we did the scaling right nowadays (it's fixed on OS X), but maybe not. You could ask on the mailing list if anyone knows more, I'm sure someone has committed code for it but maybe it hasn't made it to release yet.

Comment: Hi Inclement, thanks for your quick response. I am not that familiar yet with all functions of stackoverflow. Where, how, what mailinglist?

Comment: @BillBridge [Here](https://kivy.org/docs/contact.html) you go :)

Comment: Was there any development on this?

Comment: Still nothing? I’m having exactly the same issue and I can’t believe it hasn’t been fixed in a couple of years...

Comment: As a consequence, I moved from images on buttons etc. to icon based buttons. For this I have changed the complete GUI of my app by making use of kivyMD. This really gives your app a nice modern look & feel and all images are crisp and clear